# How can i create a canvas in a framelayout that is part of a xml layoutfile

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, canvas

I'm a total beginner on Android, I only have some java experience from school.
For programing a Game I want to draw on a canvas in a Frame layout, that's part of a xml layoutfile.
My java.class should relate to this layoutfile.
Is this possible, and if yes, how? I didn't found a solution on the web.
best regards,
Slarti.

Comment: Creating a custom view by extending View class and add that view in your FrameLayout. In your custom view file override onDraw(Canvas canvas) and draw anything on that canvas.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a custom view by extending View class and add that view in your FrameLayout. In your custom view file override `onDraw(Canvas canvas)` and draw anything on that canvas.